# How to keep spaces when removing duplicates with for loop?

Tags: python, string

So the base of my problem was to remove all duplicate characters within a string. I successfully did so by doing the following:

```
def remove_duplicates(strng):
    """
    >>> remove_duplicates("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    'The quick brown fx jmps v t lazy dg'
    """


    empty = ""  
    for ch in strng:
        if ch not in empty:
            empty = empty + ch
    return empty
```

The output I receive from this is:

```
Expected:
    'The quick brown fx jmps v t lazy dg'
Got:
    'The quickbrownfxjmpsvtlazydg'
```

It removed all the spaces which I do not want. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually pretty close to the solution, just change your code into:

```
def remove_duplicates(strng):
    empty = ""  
    for ch in strng:
        if ch not in empty or ch == " ":
            empty = empty + ch
    return empty
```

Answer (score 3):

Also there is a shorter way to do this:

```
def remove_duplicates(strng):
    return ''.join([v for i,v in enumerate(strng) if v == ' ' or strng.index(v)== i])
```

and you don't need to create a new variable like `empty`.

Comment: That's clever. Good one.